# ASP.NET Gridview dynamic Emptydatatext in server tags

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, aspxgridview

Basically I want to have some dropdownlists as filters for a gridview. when no gridview items match the selected filters it will display a message that says no items match your search(and display the dropdownlist values). I know I can accomplish this from the code behind but I was just wondering if something like this could work. Thanks

```
<asp:gridview id="gv" runat="server" EmptyDataText="<%# "no items match" & dropdownlist.selectedvalue &"stuff" %>"
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to modify your page to look like this (add emptyDataTemplate and Label)

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" 
     DataBindingComplete="gv_DataBindingComplete" 
        OnPreRender="gv_PreRender">
       <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbInfo" /></EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
```

and in your code behind use this

```
   protected void gv_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gv.Rows.Count==0)
        {
            lbInfo.Text = "no items match " + ddlTest.SelectedItem + " stuff";
        }

    }
```

Comment: I should have been more clear. I am not having problems with the filtering of the gridview. I am only concerned with displaying dynamic EmptyDataText.

Answer (score 0):

An other solution:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server">
   <EmptyDataTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#EmptyData() %>' />
   </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected string EmptyData()
{
   if (gv.Rows.Count == 0)
      {
        return "no items match" & dropdownlist.selectedvalue & "stuff";
      }
   return string.Empty;
}
```